# Cell background using decision rules

Tags: python, excel

I've made an Excel sheet with 3 pivot tables using Panda's Excelwriter. Those pivot table's were also Python objects. One pivottable contains pro age the number of people in the Netherlands at 1-1-2013, the second at 1-1-2014 and the third the increase pro age in %. Imagine, there's a decision rule that says that when the increase is more than 5% , give that cell a background colour. What's the best way to do this? Reading the excel file and then using xlwt or can this be done another way?

Comment: I don't know how extensive Panda's Excel Writer is, but if it is able to interact with the Excel object model then it should be able to create conditional formatting rules in the Excel worksheet so that Excel rather than your Python code handles the formatting (once you have specified the rules).

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to apply a conditional format to the output of the Pandas using XlsxWriter as the Excel engine. See for example [Pandas Excel output with conditional formatting](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/example_pandas_conditional.html).

After that you just need to define a suitable conditional format. For that see [XlsxWriter: Working with Conditional Formatting](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/working_with_conditional_formats.html).